# Why wont my radio button response respond to my Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've used the following code as a method to send user input data on my html site to a Google Spreadsheet:

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function postContactToGoogle() {
    var firstname=$('#firstname').val();
    var surname=$('#surname').val();
    var dob=$('#dob').val();
    var email=$('#email').val();
    var option=$('#option').val();
    $.ajax({
      url:"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfe760bJi_65cvSGfu4HckMdmAs1ahBkO7oE6njBTYZh4A/formResponse",
      data: {"entry.1012452068":firstname, "entry.1038894874":surname, "entry.1352091133":dob, "entry.1048111489":email, "entry.1786559101":option}, type: "POST", datatype: "xml", statusCode: {0:function() {window.location.replace("thankyou.html");}, 200:function(){window.location.replace("thankyou.html");}}
    });
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  First Name:<br>
    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/><br>
  Surname:<br>
  <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" placeholder="Surname"/><br>
  DoB:<br>
    <input id="dob" name="dob" type="text" placeholder="DoB"/><br>
  Email:<br>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"/><br>
  Option Pledge:<br>
    <input id="option" name="option" type="radio"/> £49 <br>
    <input id="option" name="option" type="radio"/> £69 <br>

    <input id="ButtonSubmit" name="" type="button" value="Send" onclick="postContactToGoogle()"/>
</form>
```

It all works perfectly well except for the last 2 radio button options don't appear on the spreadsheet (shown on the image below). Does anyone have an insight into what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1. Your `radio` inputs have the same `id="option"` and id's should be unique .
2. Your `radio` inputs haven't value attribute to send like `value="your value"`.

So this example should work

```js
function postContactToGoogle() {
  var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
  var surname = $('#surname').val();
  var dob = $('#dob').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var option = $("[name='option']").val();
  
  console.log({
      "entry.1012452068": firstname,
      "entry.1038894874": surname,
      "entry.1352091133": dob,
      "entry.1048111489": email,
      "entry.1786559101": option
    });
    alert("your radio button value: " + option);
   //it's working..

  //then validate your data before sending

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfe760bJi_65cvSGfu4HckMdmAs1ahBkO7oE6njBTYZh4A/formResponse",
    data: {
      "entry.1012452068": firstname,
      "entry.1038894874": surname,
      "entry.1352091133": dob,
      "entry.1048111489": email,
      "entry.1786559101": option
    },
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "xml",
    statusCode: {
      0: function() {
        alert("status:0, thank you");
        window.location.replace("thankyou.html");
      },
      200: function() {
        alert("status:200, thank you");
        window.location.replace("thankyou.html");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  First Name:
  <br>
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
  <br>Surname:
  <br>
  <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" placeholder="Surname" />
  <br>DoB:
  <br>
  <input id="dob" name="dob" type="text" placeholder="DoB" />
  <br>Email:
  <br>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
  <br>Option Pledge:
  <br>
  <input id="option1" value="Black Ballad Membership - £49" name="option" type="radio" />£49
  <br>
  <input id="option2" value="Premium Black Ballad Membership - £69" name="option" type="radio" />£69
  <br>

  <input id="ButtonSubmit" name="" type="button" value="Send" onclick="postContactToGoogle()" />
</form>
```

Comment: This looks great! Thank you for you suggestion but unfortunately it's not working and the radio button selections are still not being sent to the Google Spreadsheet. Do you suggest anything else?

Comment: it's really working test snippt and see console, alert

Comment: Go to your live form url and inspect element of your radio input name `entry.1786559101` to see is right or..?

Comment: It really is https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfe0bJi_65cvSGDQLfu4HckMdmAs1ahBkO7oE6njBTYZsdh4A/viewform
And adding the console part crashes the site. I'm honestly doing every single thing you've done but it just isn't working. Very frestrating. And thank you very much for your help

Comment: test snippt now, your radio values is `Black Ballad Membership - £49` and `Premium Black Ballad Membership - £69`

Answer (score 0):

Do following change in your code,

```
var option = $('input[name=option]:checked').val()
```

Note: There should not be the same id for two different element, you have   used id "option" for both radio.